# Как реализовать буферизацию для плеера? (отображение progressbar при загрузке трека)

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer, progress-bar, android-mediaplayer

Здравствуйте, делаю приложение для прослушивания онлайн потоков радио. 
Как реализовать показ прогресс-бара и других вьюшек, когда я например включаю какой-либо трек (онлайн радиостанция в моём случае), и пока она грузится, показывать прогресс бар?

сам прогресс бар сделал:

```
ProgressBar progressbar;
progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
```

Как я понимаю, для самого простого случая, мне нужно в какой-то метод дописать

**progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**

и

**progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);**

только я совсем не могу понять, где и куда приписать всё это ? И правильно ли я делаю вообще?

**MusicService.class**

```
public class MusicService extends Service
            implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, OnCompletionListener {

        public static final String TAG = MusicService.class.getName();

        private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 1;
        public static final String NOTIFY_PREVIOUS = null;
        public static final String NOTIFY_DELETE = null;
        public static final String NOTIFY_PAUSE = null;
        public static final String NOTIFY_PLAY = null;
        public static final String NOTIFY_NEXT = null;

        private ComponentName remoteComponentName;
        private RemoteControlClient remoteControlClient;

        AudioManager audioManager;

        // media mMediaPlayer
        private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
        // mTrack list
        private ArrayList<TrackDetails> mTrackList;
        // current position
        private int mTrackIndex;

        private String mTrackTitle = "";

        private double startTime = 0;
        private double finalTime = 0;

        private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();

        private boolean shuffle = false;
        private Random rand;
        private static boolean currentVersionSupportBigNotification = false;
        private static boolean currentVersionSupportLockScreenControls = false;

        int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1111;

        public void onCreate() {

            // create the service
            super.onCreate();
            currentVersionSupportBigNotification = UtilFunctions.currentVersionSupportBigNotification();
            currentVersionSupportLockScreenControls = UtilFunctions.currentVersionSupportLockScreenControls();
            rand = new Random();

            // initialize position
            mTrackIndex = 0;
            // create mMediaPlayer
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            initMusicPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d(TAG, "setOnCompletionListener");
                    playNext();
                }
            });
        }

        public void initMusicPlayer() {
            // set mMediaPlayer properties
            mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        }

        public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
            public MusicService getService() {
                return MusicService.this;
            }
        }

        public void setList(ArrayList<TrackDetails> theSongs) {
            mTrackList = theSongs;
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return musicBind;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void playSong() {
            // play a mTrack
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            // get mTrack
            if (mTrackList != null) {
                TrackDetails playSong = mTrackList.get(mTrackIndex);
                // get id
                // long currSong = Double.parseDouble(playSong.getId());
                // set uri
                Uri trackUri = Uri.parse(playSong.getStream_url());

                try {
                    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    Log.d(TAG, "playSong.getStream_url() : " +
                    playSong.getStream_url());
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(playSong.getStream_url()); // + "?client_id=" + Config.CLIENT_ID);
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    //              finalTime = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    //              startTime = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

                    // Log.e(TAG, "Track Info : " + mMediaPlayer.getTrackInfo());

                    /*
                     * if (oneTimeOnly == 0) { seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                     * oneTimeOnly = 1; }
                     */
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "finalTime : " + String.format("%d : %d",
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(
                                            (long) finalTime),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime)
                                    - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime))));

                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "startTime : " + String.format("%d : %d",
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(
                                            (long) startTime),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime)
                                    - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime))));
                    if(currentVersionSupportLockScreenControls){
                        RegisterRemoteClient();
                    }
                    if(currentVersionSupportLockScreenControls){
                        remoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
                    }

                newNotification();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion");
            playNext();
            /*if (mp.getCurrentPosition() < 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mp.getCurrentPosition()");
                mTrackIndex++;
                Log.d(TAG, "mTrackIndex : " +mTrackIndex);
                Log.d(TAG, "mTrackList.size() : " +mTrackList.size());
                if(mTrackIndex<=mTrackList.size())
                {
                    mp.reset();
                    //playNext();
                    playSong();
                }
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.reset();
            return false;

        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // start playback
            mp.start();

        }

        public void setSongDetails(ArrayList<TrackDetails> trackDetails, int mTrack) {
            initMusicPlayer();
            onPrepared(mMediaPlayer);
            mTrackList = trackDetails;
            mTrackIndex = mTrack;

            mTrackTitle = mTrackList.get(mTrackIndex).getTitle();
            playSong();
        }

        public int getPosn() {
            return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }

        public int getDur() {
            return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        }

        public boolean isPng() {
            return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
        }

        public void pausePlayer() {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void showNotification() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

            builder.setContentIntent(pendInt).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music_video_black).setTicker(mTrackTitle)
                    .setOngoing(true).setContentTitle("Playing").setContentText(mTrackTitle);
            Notification not = builder.build();

            startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
        }


        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void RegisterRemoteClient(){
            remoteComponentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), new NotificationBroadcast().ComponentName());
            try {
                if(remoteControlClient == null) {
                    audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(remoteComponentName);
                    Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
                    mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(remoteComponentName);
                    PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
                    remoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(mediaPendingIntent);
                    audioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(remoteControlClient);
                }
                remoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(
                        RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY |
                                RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PAUSE |
                                RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE |
                                RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP |
                                RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PREVIOUS |
                                RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_NEXT);
            }catch(Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        /**
         * Notification
         * Custom Bignotification is available from API 16
         */
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void newNotification() {
            String songName = mTrackList.get(mTrackIndex).getTitle();
            String albumName = mTrackList.get(mTrackIndex).getGenre();
            RemoteViews simpleContentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_notification);
            RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.big_notification);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_audiotrack_gray)
            .setContentTitle(songName).build();

            setListeners(simpleContentView);
            setListeners(expandedView);

            notification.contentView = simpleContentView;
            if(currentVersionSupportBigNotification){
                notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
            }

            try{
                /*long albumId = Integer.parseInt(PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(PlayerConstants.SONG_NUMBER).getId());
                Bitmap albumArt = UtilFunctions.getAlbumart(getApplicationContext(), albumId);*/
                String albumUrl = mTrackList.get(mTrackIndex).getGenre();
                URL url = new URL(albumUrl);
                Bitmap albumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                if(albumArt != null){
                    notification.contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageViewAlbumArt, albumArt);
                    if(currentVersionSupportBigNotification){
                        notification.bigContentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageViewAlbumArt, albumArt);
                    }
                }else{
                    notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageViewAlbumArt, R.drawable.ic_audiotrack_gray);
                    if(currentVersionSupportBigNotification){
                        notification.bigContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageViewAlbumArt, R.drawable.ic_audiotrack_gray);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(PlayerConstants.SONG_PAUSED){
                notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPause, View.GONE);
                notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPlay, View.VISIBLE);

                if(currentVersionSupportBigNotification){
                    notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPause, View.GONE);
                    notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPlay, View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }else{
                notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPause, View.VISIBLE);
                notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPlay, View.GONE);

                if(currentVersionSupportBigNotification){
                    notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPause, View.VISIBLE);
                    notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPlay, View.GONE);
                }
            }

            notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textSongName, songName);
            notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textAlbumName, albumName);
            if(currentVersionSupportBigNotification){
                notification.bigContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textSongName, songName);
                notification.bigContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textAlbumName, albumName);
            }
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

        /**
         * Notification click listeners
         * @param view
         */
        public void setListeners(RemoteViews view) {
            Intent previous = new Intent(NOTIFY_PREVIOUS);
            Intent delete = new Intent(NOTIFY_DELETE);
            Intent pause = new Intent(NOTIFY_PAUSE);
            Intent next = new Intent(NOTIFY_NEXT);
            Intent play = new Intent(NOTIFY_PLAY);

            PendingIntent pPrevious = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, previous, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPrevious, pPrevious);

            PendingIntent pDelete = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, delete, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnDelete, pDelete);

            PendingIntent pPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, pause, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPause, pPause);

            PendingIntent pNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, next, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNext, pNext);

            PendingIntent pPlay = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, play, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlay, pPlay);

        }

        public void seek(int posn) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(posn);
        }

        public void go() {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }

        public void playPrev() {
            mTrackIndex--;
            if (mTrackIndex != 0)
                mTrackIndex = mTrackList.size() - 1;
            playSong();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if(mMediaPlayer != null){
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer = null;
            }
            stopForeground(true);
        }

        public void setShuffle() {
            if (shuffle)
                shuffle = false;
            else
                shuffle = true;
        }

        public void playNext() {
            if (mTrackList!=null) {
                if (shuffle) {
                    int newSong = mTrackIndex;
                    while (newSong == mTrackIndex) {
                        newSong = rand.nextInt(mTrackList.size());
                    }
                    mTrackIndex = newSong;
                } else {
                    mTrackIndex++;
                    if (mTrackIndex <= mTrackList.size())
                        mTrackIndex = 0;
                }
                playSong();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Не могу найти `MediaPlayer`.. Что вы используете?

Comment: Что такое `musicSrv`?

Comment: По сути то, что вы используете для воспроизведения должно иметь интерфейс со слушателем буферизации. Только я не понимаю что вы используете. Велосипед?

Comment: @Flippy, добавил код в шапку

Comment: @Flippy,  это еще тот велосипед...((

Comment: Вы же сделали установку слушателя преперинга (она же подготовка, она же буферизация) и даже вызываете `start` у плеера в нем. Вот и перед стартом скрывайте прогрессбар.

Comment: @Flippy, как объявить в сервисе прогресс бар?